# Need help inserting commas after each character in specific part of string

Tags: c#, .net

In the program I'm working on, I need to strip the tags around certain parts of a string, and then insert a comma after each character WITHIN the tag (not not after any other characters in the string). In case this doesn't make sense, here's an example of what needs to happen -

This is a string with a < a > tag < /a > (please ignore the spaces within the tag)

(needs to become)

This is a string with a t,a,g,.

Can anyone help me with this? I've managed to strip the tags using RegEx, but I can't figure out how to insert the commas only after the characters contained within the tag. If someone could help that would be great.

@Dour High Arch I'll elaborate a little bit. The code is for a text-to-speech app that won't recognize SSML tags. When the user enters a message for the text to speech app, they have the option of enclosing a word in a < a > tag to make the speaker say the world as an acronym. Because the acronym SSML tag won't work, I want to remove the < a > tag whenever present, and place commas after each character contained in the tag to fake it out (ex: < a > test< /a > becomes t,e,s,t,). All the non-tagged words in the string do not need commas after them, just those enclosed in tags (see my first example if need be).

Comment: `myNewString = myOtherString.replace(cchar("/"),cchar(","))`

Comment: Trying to modify XML tags using regular expressions is highly problematic. It may be helpful if you explain what you are trying to accomplish; by "tag" do you mean contents of an XML element? What do you mean by "certain parts"? Does this mean there are "parts" you don't want to insert commas after? Are you going to be doing something with these tags afterward?

Comment: @Dour High Arch See my update for more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing XML is very problematic because you may have to deal with things like CDATA sections, nested elements, entities, surrogate characters, and on and on. I would use a state-based parser like ANTLR.

However, if you are just starting out with C# it is instructive to solve this using the built-in .Net string and array classes. No ANTLR, LINQ, or regular expressions needed:

```
using System;

class ReplaceAContentsWithCommaSeparatedChars
{
    static readonly string acroStartTag = "<a>";
    static readonly string acroEndTag = "</a>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "Alpha <a>Beta</a> Gamma <a>Delta</a>";
        while (true)
        {
            int start = s.IndexOf(acroStartTag);
            if (start < 0)
                break;

            int end = s.IndexOf(acroEndTag, start + acroStartTag.Length);
            if (end < 0)
                end = s.Length;

            string contents = s.Substring(start + acroStartTag.Length, end - start - acroStartTag.Length);
            string[] chars = Array.ConvertAll<char, string>(contents.ToCharArray(), c => c.ToString());
            s = s.Substring(0, start)
                + string.Join(",", chars)
                + s.Substring(end + acroEndTag.Length);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Please be aware this does not deal with any of the issues I mentioned. But then, none of the other suggestions do either.

Answer (score 2):

If you have figured out the regex, I would imagine it would be simple to capture the inner text of the tag. Then it's a really simple operation to insert the commas:

```
  var commaString = string.Join(",", capturedString.ToList());
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Sorry, I'm new to C# and haven't really done a lot of work with RegEx. Here is my code for stripping the tag,  

    string tagless = Regex.Replace(srcString, @"<(.|\n)*?>",     string.Empty);

Comment: Sorry @Tejs, forgot to tag your name in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your target string already parsed via your RegEx i.e. no tags around it...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication32
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // setup a test string
            string stringToProcess = "Test";

            // actual solution here
            string result = String.Concat(stringToProcess.Select(c => c + ","));

            // results: T,e,s,t,
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```